# Non-void function does not return a value in all control paths in recursive function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to make a recursive function where I am returned true if a string includes a comma. However, I am getting the following error:
`Non-void function does not return a value in all control paths`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `hasComma(sentence, index - 1);` if you are going to throw away the return value from this recursive call why even recurse?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
else
    hasComma(sentence, index - 1);
```

Should be:

```
else
    return hasComma(sentence, index - 1);
```

Otherwise, what are you returning?  That's what the compiler is warning you about.

Answer (score 3):

At the point you're making the recursive call, you're not returning anything.  You want to return the result of that call.

```
bool hasComma(string sentence, int index) {
    if (index == -1)
        return false;
    else if (sentence[index] == ',')
        return true;
    else
        return hasComma(sentence, index - 1);
}
```